# How to call Midlet class after button click in j2me?

Tags: java-me, midlet

When i click on button in first midlet class i need to redirect to next midlet Class. How to do this

```
if(sb.toString().equals("SUCCESS")){

              Alert success = new Alert("Login Successfully", 
                      "Your Login Process is completed!", 
                       image, AlertType.INFO);
                    //  success.setImage(image);
                      userName.setString("");
                      password.setString("");
                      display.setCurrent(success, form); 
        // here i move to next midlet       

        }
```

Comment: please upload your code, that you have tried.

Comment: i am new to j2me, i create two midlet classes, in first midlet class when i click on button i move to next midlet class

Comment: why you really dont need two midlet class for a J2ME Project, you can have one midlet and many Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If both MIDlets are part of the same MIDlet Suite, then they should be able to launch each other using Class.forName().

Quote from Sun back in the day:
"For security reasons, it is assumed that MIDlets within a MIDletSuite are packaged together for a reason and should be able to interoperate. What's implied here is that the MIDlets share a name space; in other words, each MIDlet in the MidletSuite can "see" one another. Because they can see one another, they can launch one another (Class.forName metaphor)."

If the two MIDlets are not part of the same MIDlet Suite, then there is this following trick. I haven't tried it myself though, so it's only theoretical:

For the MIDlet you wish to launch from another MIDlet, you put a PushRegistry entry in the JAD (or register it by code), listening for a socket connection on some port.
Then to launch the MIDlet from another MIDlet, you simply create a socket connection on that port using localhost or 127.0.0.1 as address. That should theoretically make the other MIDlet launch.